# How do I deselect a tabBarItem pre segue

Tags: segue, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, ios8.1, tint

I have implemented a tabBar with two tabBarItems.

Once presssed the app segues to the new VC, however when I go back to the main VC the tabBarItem is still highlighted as if it has just been pressed.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: I'm not sure that a UITabBarItem is what you want to use for segueing to another scene. Tab items should simply change the content that's displayed in the UITabBarController, and as such, it doesn't make sense *not* to highlight whichever tab corresponds to the displayed view controller.

Comment: I understand your concern, however there must be a way of deselecting it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `[tabBarHome setSelectedItem:nil];` in the same block of code that launched the segue, so when I came back to the main VC it wasn't highlighted.

I realize a tabBar is meant to be used in conjunction with a tabBarController.

Comment: But then how does the user know which tab corresponds to the visible view controller?